# IE11 Version Update

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Myself and several other users in my environment seem to be stuck on IE11 11.0.9600.16428CO while multiple other users are on a more recent iteration of IE11. It is important that we have the latest IE for testing of web apps. I attempted to install KB3148198 which I thought would remedy the situation however I am getting a message stating that the update is not applicable to my computer. Does anyone else know how to force IE to upgrade to a different version?

I should add that our local patching solution is not finding any updates for IE and MS Update is not finding any IE updates for me either however I know a newer iteration of IE11 is out there as it has been seen in our environment.

Comment: Maybe its an OS thing. W7-W8? 3148198 is a security update but does change the version of IE.

Comment: Maybe you download the wrong 32 bit or 64 bit version for your OS?

Comment: The OS is Win 7 Pro and I downloaded the 64bit variant of IE11.

Comment: What bit version of W7 Pro is it?

Comment: I'm on build 7601 Service Pack 1/64bit. IE11 64bit is also installed.

Comment: All; this is not an OS/platform issue. I'm having the exact same problem on several systems. Using Win7 Ent x64 SP1, trying various Win7 x64 cumulative updates. These updates DO increment the version number (11.0.9600.xxxxx where xxxxx is the patch revision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently deployed IE11 to my entire organization and have had this issue come up on several machines.  The error is the same: This update is not applicable to this system.

I've had some limited success with the following method:

Uninstall IE11 completely, reboot, and do a Windows Update from Microsoft rather than your WSUS server.

**NOTE** You uninstall IE11 through Windows Update -> View Installed Updates.  Do not make the mistake of removing it via Windows Features.

This will roll you back to whatever version of IE was on the machine before you upgraded to IE11.  If possible, take it all the way back to IE8, which is what originally shipped with Windows 7.  You may have to repeat this process a couple of times to roll all the way back.

In one instance, I noticed that Windows Update was offering Windows 7 Service Pack 1 as an update even though SP1 was already installed.  Reinstalling SP1 allowed the cumulative update for IE11 to install successfully.  However, this only worked on one machine.

In your case, the `CO` at the end of your version string leads me to believe that maybe you're using a language pack?  I suspect that maybe the update must match the language pack you're using, although I've never used anything other than US English.

Additionally, I have also theorized that a previous install of IE9 using the IEAK may have something to do with the issue, but I have not been able to confirm this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your solution worked for us!